# Welcome Screen Like Spotify

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, splash-screen, viewpagerindicator

Good day, I was trying to achieved the same effect of this welcome screen. But I have no idea on how to play or rather to say - the circle indicator switched to another by itself with the contents with in it.

1. **How do I create this one? The viewPager is in transparent mode and switches by itself.**
2. **Do I really need to import Jake Wharton's circleIndicator for this one?**

[image]
[image: My Welcome]

I'm stuck with this part only. I'm done with the video part. [Video Link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFkfCN8JzMAhVMFpQKHVKSAoUQjhwIBQ&url=%2Furl%3Fsa%3Di%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dimages%26cd%3D%26cad%3Drja%26uact%3D8%26ved%3D%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fgithub.com%252Fkaushikdas0%252Fspotify-like-video-welcome-screen%26bvm%3Dbv.119745492%2Cd.dGY%26psig%3DAFQjCNGJzfcCwwxKGtxqv86sYQl6YCoG2Q%26ust%3D1461228635134567&bvm=bv.119745492,d.dGY&psig=AFQjCNGJzfcCwwxKGtxqv86sYQl6YCoG2Q&ust=1461228635134567),
I know how to create fragments and set them to viewPager.I'm using FrameLayout to display the viewPager Contents.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager is suitable for you.[demo](https://github.com/rharter/ViewPager-Android)